# how to get the max path cost in binary tree

Tags: c++, visual-c++

how to get the max path cost in binary tree,
and print a vector includes all the path data elements?

i know how to get cost but dont know how to get the elements vector
any help?

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};   

int treeMaxPath(Node* root) {
    if (root== NULL)
        return 0;
    else
        return root->data + max(treeMaxPath(root->left), treeMaxPath(root->right));
 }
```

Comment: Pick *one* programming language, C or C++ (or something completely different).

Comment: cpp, but any one can solve it in c can solve in cpp

Comment: Not every C code is valid C++ code, consider for example void pointer conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Bottom up process the tree, store the `data += max subtrees`.
2. Start at the top and print the value which is now `(data - max subtrees)` and then print the max child.
3. Go top down and restore data values, `data -= max subtrees`.

Notes:

This is O(N) time complexity and O(1) for memory.
Could be changed to store max without modifying data by adding a new variable to `Node`.
It can easily be modified to print all the max paths in the tree.

```
int maxChild(const Node *root) {
   return max(root->left ? root->left.data : 0,
              root->right ? root->right.data : 0);
}

void treeBottomUp(Node* root) {
    if (root) {
       treeBottomUp(root->left);
       treeBottomUp(root->right);
       root->data += maxChild(root);
    }
}

void treeRestore(Node *root) {
   if (root) {
      root->data -= maxChild(root);
      treeRestore(root->left);
      treeRestore(root->right);
   }
}

void printMaxPath(const Node* root) {
   if (root) {
     printf("%d\n", root->data - maxChild(root));
     if (root->left && root->left.data >= maxChild(root)) {
        printMaxPath(root->left);
     } else {
        printMaxPath(root->right);
     }
   }
}
```

And to do it all:

```
void solveTree(Node *root) {
   treeBottomUp(root);
   printMaxPath(root);
   treeRestore(root);
}
```

Comment: i am sorry, i dont understand what do you mean, can you write a code for it

Comment: still dont understand what you are trying to do... why the minuses??

Comment: can you write the  function?

Answer (score 0):

Return a `pair` of cost and path. The path can be stored in `vector<Node*>`.

Answer (score 0):

After completion of call to `treeMaxPath` for the whole tree (recursive call should complete for the whole tree if you invoke it on the root) you will have the whole tree updated with their depth values.

Now you can easily do a small tracking with a simple loop to traverse from root of the tree along the highest depth values till NULL child is met.

**p.s.** I'm not sure whether your implementation of `treeMaxPath` is correct. If the data that you store at a certain node is depth, some parts of your algorithm should be changed.